# Identify non-categorical features

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A B C
1 224 A
2 9978 B
3 5 D
```

As you can see column B is not categorical. How would I use sklearn or pandas to use to identify non-categorical numerical / regressive features?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame([[1,224,'A'],[2,9978,'B'],[3,5,'D']],columns=['A','B','C'])
print(data)

>>>
   A     B  C
0  1   224  A
1  2  9978  B
2  3     5  D
<<<

numeric_cols=data._get_numeric_data().columns
print(numeric_cols)

>>>
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
<<<

print(data[numeric_cols])

>>>
   A     B
0  1   224
1  2  9978
2  3     5
<<<
```

Comment: its supposed to only select B

Comment: column `A` is numeric.

Comment: I am trying to get the numeric non-categorical features, (I just realised) an id changes with increment while numeric non-categorical ones do not

Comment: You might want to set the index of the dataframe to column `A` using `set_index`? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html